# query table using another lookup table sql

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join, lookup

I'm looking for all names and URLs of artists that a user with user_id 57 has stored.

Table "artists"

```
    id | name         | url
    ---+--------------+--------
    01 | Luke Combs   | url-1
    02 | Jason Aledan | url-2
    03 | Upchurch     | url-3
    04 | Lee Brice    | url-4
    05 | Khalid       | url-5
```

Lookup table `user_artists`:

```
    user_id | artist_id
   ---------+-----------
         02 | 05
         15 | 01
         37 | 01
         57 | 03
         57 | 01
         28 | 02
```

Desired outcome for user_id=57:

```
    name        | url
    ------------+--------
    Luke Combs  | url-1
    Upchurch    | url-3
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT name, url, user_id 
FROM artists, user_artists 
INNER JOIN user_artists.user_id ON artists.name 
WHERE user_id = 57;
```

The SQL queries seem so confusing to me. I'm not even sure if inner join is the right one. I spent the whole afternoon googling these queries and finally came with this via a SQL generator. Any help, thanks much!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. You should **most definitely NOT** mix the two styles!

Comment: thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what **concrete RDBMS** this is for - and the various RDBMS are not 100% compatible in how they "interpret" the SQL standards - but I guess something like this *should work* in just about any RDBMS:

```
SELECT name, url, user_id 
FROM artists a
INNER JOIN user_artists ua ON ua.artist_id = a.id
WHERE ua.user_id = 57;
```

Basically, you take those rows from `user_artists` where the `user_id` matches your desired value, and then you join the `artists` table via the "link" between  `user_artists.artist_id` to the `artist.id` column - and that produces your desired output.

Comment: Right, sorry for that, using mysql (phpMyAdmin 4.9.2)